# understand if systray displayed in a desktop environment

Tags: desktop

I'm author of a couple off apps that make use of systray.
Recently, since in some desktops only the indicator is supported (see ubuntu unity), I introduced a check and if indicator is supported the app uses indicator in place of systray.

```
try:
    import appindicator
    HAS_APPINDICATOR = True
except: HAS_APPINDICATOR = False
```

which works pretty good, the problem is that I still would like to use systray in place of indicator if systray is supported. Is there a way to understand if systray is supported/not blocked from the current desktop environment?